# Class directive doesn't work, but works whenever changed to element directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I'm encountering a very weird issue where class directives just will not work. So I'm trying to implement the following directive.

```
appModule.directive('btn', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            if (element.hasClass('btn-icon') || element.hasClass('btn-float')) {
                Waves.attach(element, ['waves-circle']);
            }

            else if (element.hasClass('btn-light')) {
                Waves.attach(element, ['waves-light']);
            }

            else {
                Waves.attach(element);
            }

            Waves.init();
        }
    }
});
```

Then In my HTML I just have a button with the class btn, like so.

```
<button type="button" class='btn btn-success'>Hello</button>
```

But for some reason it just won't EVER fire the directive. I've tried debugging using console.log, it's just not entering the directive itself. But when I change restrict: 'C' from C to E, it works fine! (with altered HTML ofcourse.)

Now we do use a small framework on top of angularJS, but haven't found anything weird in there. (I recently joined the team, and the orignal developer of the framework didn't write any documentation and has left the team).

What could possibly be a reason why this directive would not work? I've googled everywhere but I can't find anyone with a similar issue.

Comment: You have a [working code](https://plnkr.co/edit/wX71DhCWptiaiN0TtptN?p=preview). Try it without `Waves` in it, to see if it at least fires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking at the code for hours, I finally found what it was. So someone that wrote the official code added in this line of code....

```
$compileProvider.cssClassDirectivesEnabled(false);
```

Changed this to true, and it works..